# Finding range of rational function

Tags: quartics

$$y=\frac {x^2+ ax-2}{x-a}$$

I have been told that the range of the function is set of all real values then I am told to find the set of values of a.

My attempt:

$(x-a)y=x^2+ax-2$

$x^2+x(a-y)+ ay-2=0$

Now putting D>=0 as I have assumed x belonging to real

$a^2 +y^2-6ay+8 \ge 0$

Now this equation is quadratic in $y$ and is positive therefore this should have discriminant less than $0$ as the graph will lie above x axis as leading coeffecient is positive .I get :

$36a^2-32-4a^2 \le 0$

Using this I got the set of values of a to be $[-1,1]$ but the values of a is given by
$(-1,1)$......where am I doing wrong

Comment: Is it $$y=\frac{x^2+ax-2}{x-a}$$?

Comment: Use mathjax to write

Comment: And the range depends on $a$

Comment: One way of seeing the issue is that if numerator and denominator of original expression have a root same ($x=a$) here then the whole expression becomes linear for all $x\neq a$ and un defined  for $x=a$. Numerator has root $x=a$ for $a=\pm 1$

Comment: And that if $D=0$ in the quadratic in $x$ essentially means numerator has a root $x=a$ so this case is not to be excluded..

Comment: @samjoe how does D=0 in the quadratic of x means root has a root of x=a

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the inequality is given by

$$(y-3a)^2+8(1-a^2)>0$$

Comment: I forgot to include but wouldn't the discriminant be greater than equal to zero

Comment: I have written the discriminant for you, it depends on the parameter $a$!

Comment: It depends on a alright but shouldn't the discriminant be greater than equal to zero

Comment: for a = 1, y cant take the value 3 and for a = -1 , y cant take -3 . but it has to be all the real numbers as range. so they are excluded. cant take cause in the given form, denominator becomes 0.